# Trying to convert existing synchronous XmlHttpRequest object to be asynchronous to keep up with current fads

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Soo, I keep getting slammed with cautions from Chrome about how synchronous XmlHttpRequest calls are being deprecated, and I've decided to have a go at trying to convert my use-case over in order to keep up with this fad...

In this case, I have an ~9 year old JS object that has been used as the central (and exemplary) means of transporting data between the server and our web-based applications using synchronous XHR calls. I've created a chopped-down version to post here (by gutting out a lot of sanity, safety and syntax checking):

```
function GlobalData()
{
    this.protocol = "https://";
    this.adminPHP = "DataMgmt.php";
    this.ajax = false;
    this.sessionId = "123456789AB";
    this.validSession = true;
    this.baseLocation = "http://www.example.com/";
    this.loadResult = null;

    this.AjaxPrep = function()
    {
        this.ajax = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            try { this.ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) { this.ajax = false; } }
    }

    this.FetchData = function (strUrl)
    {
        if ((typeof strURL=='string') && (strURL.length > 0))
        {
            if (this.ajax === false)
            {
                this.AjaxPrep();
                if (this.ajax === false) { alert('Unable to initialise AJAX!'); return ""; }
            }

            strURL = strURL.replace("http://",this.protocol); // We'll only ask for data from secure (encrypted-channel) locations...
            if (strURL.indexOf(this.protocol) < 0) strURL = this.protocol + this.adminPHP + strURL;
            strURL += ((strURL.indexOf('?')>= 0) ? '&' : '?') + 'dynamicdata=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sessionId);
            if (this.validSession) strURL += "&sessionId=" + this.sessionId;
            this.ajax.open("GET", strURL, false);
            this.ajax.send();
            if (this.ajax.status==200) strResult = this.ajax.responseText;
            else alert("There was an error attempting to communicate with the server!\r\n\r\n(" + this.ajax.status + ") " + strURL);
            if (strResult == "result = \"No valid Session information was provided.\";")
            {
                alert('Your session is no longer valid!');
                window.location.href = this.baseLocation;
            }
        }
        else console.log('Invalid data was passed to the Global.FetchData() function. [Ajax.obj.js line 62]');
        return strResult;
    }

    this.LoadData = function(strURL)
    {
        var s = this.FetchData(strURL);
        if ((s.length>0) && (s.indexOf('unction adminPHP()')>0))
        {
            try
            {
                s += "\r\nGlobal.loadResult = new adminPHP();";
                eval(s);
                if ((typeof Global.loadResult=='object') && (typeof Global.loadResult.get=='function')) return Global.loadResult;
            } catch(e) { Global.Log("[AjaxObj.js] Error on Line 112: " + e.message); }
        }
        if ( (typeof s=='string') && (s.trim().length<4) ) 
            s = new (function() { this.rowCount = function() { return -1; }; this.success = false; });
        return s;
    }
}
var Global = new GlobalData();
```

This "Global" object is referenced literally hundreds of times across 10's of thousands of lines code as so:

```
// Sample data request...
var myData = Global.LoadData("?fn=fetchCustomerData&sortByFields=lastName,firstName&sortOrder=asc");
if ((myData.success && (myData.rowCount()>0)) 
{ 
    // Do Stuff...
    // (typically build and populate a form, input control 
    // or table with the data)
}
```

The server side API is designed to handle all of the myriad kinds of requests encountered, and, in each case, to perform whatever magic is necessary to return the data sought by the calling function. A sample of the plain-text response to a query follows (the API turns the result(s) from any SQL query into this format automatically; adjusting the fields and data to reflect the retrieved data on the fly; the sample data below has been anonymized;):

```
/* Sample return result (plain text) from server:
function adminPHP()
{
    var base = new DataInterchangeBase();
    this.success = true;
    this.colName = function(idNo) { return base.colName(idNo); }
    this.addRow = function(arrRow) { base.addRow(arrRow); }
    this.get = function(cellId,rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(cellId,rowId); }
    this.getById = function(cellId,rowId) { return base.getByIdVal(cellId,rowId); }
    this.colExists = function(colName) { return ((typeof colName=='string') && (colName.length>0)) ? base.findCellId(colName) : -1; }
    base.addCols( [ 'id','email','firstName','lastName','namePrefix','nameSuffix','phoneNbr','companyName' ] );
    this.id = function(rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(0,rowId); }
    this.email = function(rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(1,rowId); }
    this.firstName = function(rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(2,rowId); }
    this.lastName = function(rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(3,rowId); }
    this.longName = function(rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(5,rowId); }
    this.namePrefix = function(rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(6,rowId); }
    this.nameSuffix = function(rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(7,rowId); }
    this.companyName = function(rowId) { return base.getByAbsPos(13,rowId); }
    base.addRow( [ "2","biff@nexuscons.com","biff","broccoli","Mr.","PhD","5557891234","Nexus Consulting",null ] );
    base.addRow( [ "15","happy@daysrhere.uk","joseph","chromebottom","Mr.","","5554323456","Retirement Planning Co.",null ] );
    base.addRow( [ "51","michael@sunrisetravel.com","mike","dolittle","Mr.","",""5552461357","SunRise Travel",null ] );
    base.addRow( [ "54","info@lumoxchemical.au","patricia","foxtrot","Mrs,","","5559876543","Lumox Chem Supplies",null ] );
    this.query = function() { return " SELECT `u`.* FROM `users` AS `u` WHERE (`deleted`=0) ORDER BY `u`.`lastName` ASC, `u`.`firstName` LIMIT 4"; }
    this.url = function() { return "https://www.example.com/DataMgmt.php?fn=fetchCustomerData&sortByFields=lastName,firstName&sortOrder=asc&dynamicdata=13647037920&sessionId=123456789AB\"; }
    this.rowCount = function() { return base.rows.length; }
    this.colCount = function() { return base.cols.length; }
    this.getBase = function() { return base; }
}
*/
```

In virtually every instance where this code is called, the calling function cannot perform its work until it receives all of the data from the request in the object form that it expects.

So, I've read a bunch of stuff about performing the asynchronous calls, and the necessity to invoke a call-back function that's notified when the data is ready, but I'm a loss as to figuring out a way to return the resultant data back to the original (calling) function that's waiting for it without having to visit every one of those hundreds of instances and make major changes in every one (i.e. change the calling code to expect a call-back function as the result instead of the expected data and act accordingly; times 100's of instances...)

Sooo, any guidance, help or suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's *not* a fad. (Nor is it a new thing.)

Comment: It's an unnecessary change simply for change's sake. There's _rarely_ a good reason for **REMOVING** extant functionality, and this is a perfect example of that (along with such joys as Chrome deciding to take `input.selectionStart` and `input.selectionEnd` away from `input.type='number'` and `input.type='email'` fields)..  They're just dumb bureaucratic examples of unnecessary meddling for no _genuine **BENEFIT**_ whatsoever... 

In any case, thanks for the helpful input on the actual problem...</sarcasm>

Comment: Actually I agree that the synchronous option shouldn't be removed because although it makes complete sense for it to be deprecated actually removing it will break things. But this is definitely not a "current fad", and I wouldn't have commented if you hadn't described it as such. Your code base is nine years old,  but async Ajax has been best practice longer than that.

Comment: It's only "best practice" in the general sense. In specific cases it's a perfectly good solution. From everything I've seen so far, making this asynchronous is going to necessitate implementing a significantly more complicated solution for no net benefit to us. If Google wasn't pelting our logs with "This is deprecated and could be removed at any time!" warnings, we'd have no impetus to do anything at all with it. The concern though, is that one day Google's going to f us in the a and we'll get blindsided when some percentage of our users suddenly can't do anything at all with the site...

Comment: Yeah, using asynchronous calls in a new project isn't usually a problem, and with promises the code can still read as reasonably linear (as compared to nested callbacks), but converting an existing large project is a lot of work. Sorry, I'm not aware of any shortcuts that would help with your codebase.

Comment: Ironically, while investigating options, I researched methods for implementing a sleep() function in JS, and in one thread here on that subject there was both, a person trying to solve this exact problem (converting synchronous XHR to asynchronous) AND a person who used synchronous calls to a PHP script to achieve the desired sleep effect. It's a shame that the ECMA standard doesn't specify implementing a function to pause JS execution while nevertheless allowing the browser's thread itself to continue pumping messages...